# Am i missing something when trying to use slideToggle JQuery?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use slideToggle on my table row so that when clicked they show additional information.

I cant seem to reference the table row within the JQuery correctly as i keep getting an error saying 'testMe' is undefined.

I have been able to try a quick test that pop up an alert when clicked which works fine but when i try and use the JQuery it just wont work.

This is how i am calling the alert()

server side code..

```
 tr = New TableRow
            tr.Attributes.Add("onclick", "testMe(' " & dt.Item("login_name").ToString & " ') ")
```

then client side..

```
function testMe(myLogin) {

    alert(myLogin);
}
```

This works fine but my JQuery below does not. Please can someone advise where i am going wrong

Same server side code as above..

```
$(document).ready(function (testMe) {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        $(this).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Thank You

Comment: What do you want to do in the tr click? Alert, slideToggle, both?

Comment: well i was hoping to use slideToggle but now i think it wont work. What i am looking to do is get a basic popup box that show some information like a dialog box maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the login data as `data-attribute` then show its value on click.

And you have to remove testMe as argument from the `document.ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-login'));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/cusabuvufa/1/

Comment: I tried this and i did get a pop up but i still get error about testMe not defined, is there something i need to change server side?

Comment: Yep remove the click handler and add a data-login attribute on the element.

Comment: If i am honest i am not sure how to (remove the click handler and add a data-login attribute )

Comment: Remove: tr.Attributes.Add("onclick", "testMe(' " & dt.Item("login_name").ToString & " ') ") and Add: tr.Attributes.Add("data-login", dt.Item("login_name").ToString)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This works now but is the same as the alert i tried previously. Do you know how i could do the same thing but with a styled popup?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use div instead of table, if possible. A table row's height can not be reduced if there is no room for contents.

But if you must use a table, it is possible to wrap the contents in a div (or span). Basically, change -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

to -

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>Column 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>Column 2</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, change the script to animate the container divs -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr').click(function () {
            $(this).find("div").slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would love to be able to create the table this way but i have to create the table server side. I didnt want to paste the whole table in as it is very long but if this helps i can change my question to include how the table is rendered?